# Get the current ID from Fancybox class

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm trying to call Fancybox 3 layer and receive current ID from element using Class. But it still returns undefined variable.

```
$(".cerrar_actividad").fancybox({
  afterLoad: function () {
    alert($(this.element).attr("id"))
  }
});
```

Here JSfiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/3bfcrstc/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Original element is stored into `opts.$orig` (for customization) and this is how you would get ID:

```
afterLoad: function( instance, current ) {
    alert( current.opts.$orig.attr("id") );
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/3bfcrstc/5/

Answer (score 0):

To get the `id` of the clicked element in the `afterLoad` event handler you can get the `context` from the `$lastFocus` object as returned in the `instance` argument, like this:

```js
$(".cerrar_actividad").fancybox({
  afterLoad: function(instance, current) {
    alert($(instance.$lastFocus.context).prop("id"))
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.1.25/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.1.25/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>

<a id="image1" rel="gallery" class="cerrar_actividad" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6s-a7Xz_Qqc"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a id="image2" rel="gallery" class="cerrar_actividad" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6s-a7Xz_Qqc"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```